# Generalization of the mean value theorem for the space $C[a,b]$

Tags: calculus

Does there exist the following generalization of the mean value theorem for the space $C[a,b]$ ?

Let $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be a continuously differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ function, and $y,z\in C[a,b]$. Then there exists $\xi\in C[a,b]$ such that
$$
f(y(x))-f(z(x))=f'(\xi(x))(y(x)-z(x)) \quad \forall x\in[a,b].
$$

Comment: The question is: Can $\xi(x)$ be chosen continuously (!) depending on $x$ ?  ($x\in [a,b]$)